# S3 and spark . Multiple Hive targets on S3 . Use s3:sse for some and do not use s3:sse for some hive tables

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I want to write a spark application in which I read from multiple hive tables and writes to multiple hive table . However here is the quirk.

All the hive tables are external hive tables with data residing on S3.

Some s3 buckets require s3:sse encryption when writing  and some buckets do not .

From my understand , I can only set the property fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm at a global level .

How do I go about this . I am pretty certain this is a common use case.

I guess the question I am asking is the following.

consider that I am reading from a hive table and writing to a hive table within a spark application . 
consider that both hive tables are external with data on S3. 
however , the table reads from a non encrypted bucket and writes into a bucket that requires encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop 2.8.0 lets you add [per-bucket configurations](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Configurations_different_S3_buckets), which will let you do exactly what you want; when you upgrade Spark to use the 2.8.0 JARs you can use this feature from Spark.